# Python splitlines() into list horizontally

Tags: python

I have this code:

```python
url = requests.get('https://sneakernews.com/release-dates/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col lg-2 sm-3 popular-releases-box'})

for tag in tags:
    link = tag.find('a').get('href')
    tag1 = str(tag.text)
    tag2 = tag1.splitlines()
    print(tag2)
    if link == 'javascript:void(0);':
        link = 'Link not available'
```

I have this output:

```
['March  ', 'OFF WHITE x Nike Air VaporMax']
['04.12  ', 'Nike Air VaporMax 97 "Silver Bullet"']
['April  ', 'adidas Yeezy Desert Rat 500 "Blush"']
['05.15  ', 'ACRONYM x Nike Air VaporMax MOC 2']
```

The above output is 2 lists vertically, I am trying to make each line a list horizontally.

Comment: Please show some sample input, and the actual and expected output. It's too hard to figure out what your problem is from just a vague description. If it isn't obvious how to do that, please read the [mcve] help.

Comment: edited, shows output

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you just want to print the two elements of each `tag2` on separate lines? All of `for subtag in tag2: print(subtag)` or `print(*tag2, sep='\n')` or `print('\n'.join(tag2))` do that, if that's what you want.

Comment: if you change print(tag2) to print(tag2[0]) it prints out the row of dates on the left, instead of the date and name straight across.. which is what im trying to do, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) that can be done like:

#### Code:

```
the_tags = [[x.strip() for x in tag.text.splitlines()] for tag in tags]
result = [x for x in zip(*the_tags)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://sneakernews.com/release-dates/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col lg-2 sm-3 popular-releases-box'})

the_tags = [[x.strip() for x in tag.text.splitlines()] for tag in tags]
print([x for x in zip(*the_tags)])
```

#### Results:

```
[('March', '04.12', 'April', '05.15'), 
 ('OFF WHITE x Nike Air VaporMax', 'Nike Air VaporMax 97 "Silver Bullet"', 
  'adidas Yeezy Desert Rat 500 "Blush"', 'ACRONYM x Nike Air VaporMax MOC 2'
 )
]
```

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors on the "print([*zip(*the_tags)])" when i try to run it

nevermind, fixed it

Comment: So, i ran it and its giving me the same thing i was trying to fix.. if u run "print(result[0])" it will give you a list of all the dates, instead of the first date alone.. and "print(result[1])" gives you all the names

Comment: I am guessing you are using Python 2.  When you *fixed* it I am also guessing, that the change you made was not what you were expecting.  I have made an edit which should work on both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: all i did to fix it was run it on python 3, which gave me the result above

Comment: So if the result above it not what you want then I do not understand what you want...